# My first angular app does not work as expected

Tags: html, angular

I started to play around with Angular, I downloaded all the relevant stuff, but I'm getting the following output (I should see some name instead of `{{ name }}`):

[image]

**Here is `app.component.html`:**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name">
<p>{{ name }}</p>
```

**Here is `app.component.ts`:**

```
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.styl']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      name = 'ddd';
    }
```

**Here is `app.component.spec.ts`:**

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it(`should have as title 'my-first-app'`, () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('my-first-app');
  });

  it('should render title in a h1 tag', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('h1').textContent).toContain('Welcome to my-first-app!');
  });
});
```

Comment: What does your app.module look like?

Comment: What do you see in the dev tools?

Comment: Everything looks correct man! You should see ddd in input and the p tag

Comment: Did you make this Angular application from scratch? Or did you use `@angular/cli`?

Comment: are u trying to load stylus file in styleUrl?

Comment: sorry if sound stupid, but.. you write in console "ng serve" and in navigator "localhost:4200" ?

Comment: Since you are using the `ngModel` directive on the input field, you'll need to import the Angular [FormsModule](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel). Once you've that imported in your project, Angular will start updating your model with the form fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very good start is using the [cli](https://cli.angular.io/) to initialize your project.

> The Angular CLI makes it easy to create an application that already
>   works, right out of the box. It already follows our best practices!

First
`npm install -g @angular/cli`

Then
`ng new my-dream-app`

Then
`cd my-dream-app`

Finally
`ng serve`

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things you can check:

- Debugging starts from Browser's **console** tab. Check if you've an error. If yes then click on that error. Angular doc will guide you what mistakes you've made.
- Check if you have imported `FormsModule` in you `app.module.ts` file.
- Alternatively, You can verify if you've a successful started the initial project like this also (this will also confirm that you've error with `FormsModule`):

In `app.component.html` file

```
 <input (keyup)="onKey($event)">
 <p>{{values}}</p>
```

In `app.component.ts` file

```
values = '';
onKey(event: any) { // without type info
   this.values += event.target.value + ' | ';
}
```

Write something and check if this works. If yes then you've error with `FormsModule` and not with Angular project.

*Note: just to verify in start you can disable the test cases.*